# Replacing expression matches in Ruby with a table look up

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a large string of text and am using a regex to search for a certain delimited string key.  For example, I am interested in finding all occurrences of `[!v some_word]` in the text.

I already have the regex to find the occurrences.  What I want to do is use the found `"some_word"` to look up a value in a database and replace the whole occurrence `"[!v some_word]"` with the value I found.

Is there a way to do this as a one liner using regex's?  And as a catch...`"some_word"` might not be defined in the database, and in those cases I would want to ignore the match and just leave it.

My regex is:

```
/(\[!v\s+([a-z\d_]+)\s*\])/
```

The text would contain something like:

```
This proposal is created for [!v client_name].  As such [!v client_name] maintains personal rights...
```

The database would contain an entry keyed by `"client_name"` whose value might be `"Google"`.  So I want to be able to find all instances as marked by the `[!v...]`, determine the key (e.g., `client_name`), and then replace the `[!v...]` with the value associated with that key.  You could also assume that the value could be looked up through some association or even in a parameter array.

Comment: show us your code(regex) and a sample string along with what's in your database (what field? object? column? ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Use the form of [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) or [`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) that takes a block.  The block will receive the match data as its parameters.  You can put arbitrary code in the block that does a database query.  The block should return a string, which will then be used to replace the portion of the text that matched the regex.  The `g` in `gsub` stands for `global`, so it will process all matching parts of the string, not the just first one.

```
new_test = test.gsub(regex_pattern) do |match|
  # do database query
  # return a string
end
```

Comment: I updated my original question above to include the regex.  I seem to be getting only the whole group in my block which as |whole, key| as its parameters.  "key" always seems be null by "whole" gets the [!v key].

Comment: Oh, another hint is that you can use the magic variables like `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` to get the parts of the string that correspond to parentheses in the regex.  Maybe that's what you were talking about.

Comment: Yes, it was the $1, etc. That I was missing.  Thanks.